# Exibir dados do mysql usando angularjs/codeigniter

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, angularjs-factorys

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em CodeIgniter 3 e me deparei com o seguinte problema.
Quero importar os dados da tabela do banco de dados e exibir numa página php.

No meu controller criei a função:

```
public function relacionar() {
    $query = $this->produto->listagem();
     return json_encode($query->result());
}
```

No arquivo produto.js criei a seguinte factory:

```
app.factory('ProdutoService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

        return {
            retornaDados: function () {
                var deffered = $q.defer();
                $http({url: window.location.origin + '/ged/produto/relacionar', method: 'GET'})
                        .then(function (response) {
                            deffered.resolve(response.data);
                        });

                return deffered.promise;
            }

        };
    }]);
```

Desejo adicionar o retorno a variável $scope.list, desse modo procedi da seguinte maneira:

```
 function ($scope, $http, $log, $timeout, ProdutoService) {
        $scope.list = function () {
            ProdutoService.retornaDados().then(function (retorno) {
                return retorno;  
            });
        };
```

Ao invés de obter a resposta que veio do banco de dados, o return recebe a função e não os dados.
Segue o retorno:

```
 function () {
            ProdutoService.retornaDados().then(function (retorno) {
                console.log(retorno);  
            });
        }
```

Qual deve ser maneira correta de obter os dados e não a funcão como retorno?
O fato de usar o codeIgniter pode estar interferindo no dados?

obs: ja testei a função que busca os dados no banco e a mesma está devolvendo um array json.

Answer (score 0):

Seu código está retornando o retorno da função, para a função ProdutosService.retornaDados().
Acredito que um return antes funcionaria:

```js
 function ($scope, $http, $log, $timeout, ProdutoService) {
        $scope.list = function () {
            return ProdutoService.retornaDados()
            .then(function (retorno) {
                return retorno;  
            });
        };
```